# How to get short URL inside my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, url, short, short-url

I need to get a short URL from a long one (that I made inside my app). I think that I already read about this, but I couldn't find it anymore here in SO.

Anyone has a piece of code or directions to point this out?

Best Regards

Comment: This question is very similar to yours, and may provide some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252470/implementing-url-shorteners-in-my-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this one, from brandontreb of iCodeBlog

```
NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*API URL=*%@",link];
NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
error:nil];
```